# Setting customized parameters in stm

Tags: r, topic-modeling, quanteda

Using this option:

```
library(quanteda)

dfmat_ire <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010)
library("quanteda.textmodels")
quant_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove = stopwords("english"))
set.seed(100)
if (require("stm")) {
    my_lda_fit20 <- stm(quant_dfm, K = 20, verbose = FALSE, init.type = "LDA")
    plot(my_lda_fit20)
}
```

How is it possible to set the `α` and `β` parameter for lda?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to provide `init.type = "Custom"` and `control=list(custom.beta=...)`. From the reference:

> **custom.beta** If init.type="Custom" you can pass your own initialization of the topic-word distributions beta to use as an
> initialization. Please note that this takes some care to be sure that
> it is provided in exactly the right format. The number of topics and
> vocab must match exactly. The vocab must be in the same order. The
> values must not be pathological (for instance setting the probability
> of a single word to be 0 under all topics). The beta should be
> formatted in the same way as the piece of a returned `stm model`object
> `stmobj$beta$logbeta`. It should be a list of length the number of
> levels of the content covariate. Each element of the list is a K by V
> matrix containing the logged word probability conditional on the
> topic. If you use this option we recommend that you use max.em.its=0
> with the model initialization set to random, inspect the returned form
> of `stmobj$beta$logbeta` and ensure that it matches your form

Comment: thank you, but is it again the lda (latent semantic analysis) option?

Comment: Yes. Good posts [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/199/what-does-the-alpha-and-beta-hyperparameters-contribute-to-in-latent-dirichlet-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787484/why-do-we-need-the-hyperparameters-beta-and-alpha-in-lda).